# SwiftUI: add Text below a Button

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

So I'm building my first App and trying to get some Text below the Button, but it should still be a part of the button. So thats what i got:

```
Button{
    print("tapped")
} label: {
                
   Image("Wand")
       .resizable()
       .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
   }
   .font(.title3)
   .background(Color.gray)
   .foregroundColor(.black)
   .cornerRadius(20)
```

It looks like this:

[image]

But I want is this:

[image]

I've tried putting a `VStack` into the `Label`, but the `Text` stays in the gray button

Comment: Use custom label style with VStack inside. Example is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69687031/12299030.

Comment: It sounds like you want a `VStack` with an `onTapGesture` with a `RoundedRectangle` with an `Image` `overlay` on top, a `Text` on the bottom`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may help you

```
public struct VerticalLabelStyle: LabelStyle {
    public let spacing: CGFloat
    
    public init(spacing: CGFloat = 8) {
        self.spacing = spacing
    }
    
    public func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: spacing) {
            configuration.icon
            configuration.title
        }
    }
}


public struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text: String = ""

    public var body: some View {
        Label {
            Text(text)
        } icon: {
            Image(systemName: "gamecontroller.fill")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 44, height: 44, alignment: .center)
        }
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        .labelStyle(VerticalLabelStyle())
        .onTapGesture(perform: onTap)

    }
    
    func onTap() {
        text = "tapped"
    }
}
```

If you have some questions please ask

Comment: Why not use a `Button` that has a `Label` as the body?

Comment: Yes, I think we can use a `Button` that has a `Label` as the body. But the first thing with image and text that I mention was the `Label` and I provided this solution)

Answer (score 0):

Your idea with a VStack is the correct way. You just have to keep in mind where to place your modifiers. In your case you placed them on the button level. Meaning they are applied to the entire label, which is the reason why your Text is inside the gray background. Just update also the place of your modifiers inside your VStack.
Here is are short example:

```
    Button {
        // Your button action
    } label: {
        VStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.black) // new position of background modifier that is only applied on your Image (here a rectangle)
            Text("Foo")
                .font(.title3)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
            // These modifiers could stay on button level, but I moved them here to explicitly show where they applied
        }
    }
```

Keep in mind you can put any view inside the label of your button and that in this case the Text is part of the button and will trigger the action if a user taps on it. If you only want that the Image is the tap action wrap your button inside a VStack containing only the Image and a Text as the second part of the Stack like this:

```
    VStack {
        Button {
            // Your button action
        } label: {
            VStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.black)
            }
        }
        Text("Foo")
            .font(.title3)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
    }
```